# Design of capacitive proximity sensor

Tags: sensor, proximity-sensor, capacitive

I am currently designing a microgripper for which I need a proximity/distance sensor.

Please refer to the image below for design requirements.

Due to the force application (as shown in the image), the surfaces A and B undergo bending phenomenon. I need sensors to identify the distance between these surfaces during the bending process. I plan to use capacitive proximity sensor IC (as the material is plastic) either on surface A or both of them to create a capacitor like condition and measure the change in the distance between them.

The  dimensions surface are 18mm(length) and 4mm(height)

Could you suggest which proximity solution might work in this case? My idea is to use the two surfaces as capacitor plates but I need help in how to create a detection system.

[image: http://imgur.com/mSxEBvJ]

Comment: Thank you for sharing your project. Have you got a question?

Comment: Nice project and good luck but aren't you forgetting something....

Comment: sorry. my mistake. too eager to ask for suggestions.

Comment: What does the distance information that you think you need get used for i.e.  justify that measuring capacitance to calculate distance is the bottom line parameter you need (rather than using a strain gauge to directly measure force).

Comment: @Andyaka This microgripper is one component of my work. I need to be able to control the jaws (i.e. the precise amount of opening and closing) as I will be holding a tube (with fluid flow) and can hence control the flow. Strain gauge can be used for data acquisition but not as an MEMS device.

Comment: Mems device? What has this to do with your question and why would a capacitance sensor fall under the banner of mems?

Comment: @Andyaka the entire design - including this microgripper (which is very small in size ) including the sensing system will constitute a MEMS device (in it's final form). The present design that I present above is still a concept phase design. Capacitance sensor is relevant because it can be a part of this system, including circuitry etc. (again in the final form)

Comment: 18 mm hardly constitutes the label mems

Comment: @Andyaka I mentioned this to be a first concept working. MEMS is for later exploration.

Answer (score 1):

Cypress makes good products for this that are generally easy to use.  They have a largely GUI based development environment and unlike a lot of manufacturers loads of very good documentation about it.

http://www.cypress.com/documentation/application-notes/an92239-proximity-sensing-capsense

They can do what you want and do a good job of guiding you along the way.

Comment: I just went through their work and as I make out their solutions are meant to be deployed directly. It won't be helpful to me as I am looking to maybe use some IC's as capacitive sensor and not designs which they have. GUI is of no relevance to me.

Comment: @AmanGarg In your question you say "I need help in how to create a detection system", so this is actually a decent answer. You have to start somewhere, there isn't going to be some magical IC that will just work. AN92239 is a guide on how to design a proximity sensing solution, and their designs are examples, not necessarily meant to be directly deployed.